# Existe alguma maneira de conseguir uma determinada linha de uma string?

Tags: string, lua

Tenho essa string de exemplo:

```
s = [[Pão
com
Requeijão]]
```

Existe alguma maneira de pegar somente a segunda linha da string? Se sim, como?

Comment: Pão com requeijão é tão bão.

Comment: Psé ne 

Answer (score 2):

A segunda linha da string `s` é o resultado de `s:match("\n(.-)\n")`.

Comment: Dps disso é necessário um slice p/ pular o \n: `:sub(1)`.

Comment: @Hydro, por que? O resultado de `s:match("\n(.-)\n")` não contém nenhum `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

**Sim, existe.**

Em lua o término de uma linha é sinalizada por `\n`, ou seja, a solução é quebrar a linha a partir do `\n` e pegar o segundo elemento. Veja como ficaria:

```
if s:sub(-1) ~= "\n" then s = s.."\n" end --Garante que tenha um '\n' no final da linha
linhas = {} --Cria um array/table

for linha in string.gmatch(s, "(.-)\n") do --Itera sobre as linhas
    table.insert(linhas, linha) --Adiciona ao array linhas
end
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YWnv70).

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria o split da string baseado nas linhas e depois pegaria a segunda linha indexando a tabela resultante. Ex:

```
s=[[Pão
com
Requeijão]]

function split(str, sep)
    local ret = {}
    str = table.concat{str, sep}
    for part in string.gmatch(str, "(.-)" .. sep) do
        table.insert(ret, part)
    end
    return ret
end

lines = split(s, "\n")

print(lines[2])
```